# How to keep a webpage on the screen after link click and refresh only after the new page loaded?

Tags: performance, optimization, webserver

I've seen some websites do it, I'll just explain what happens.

Normally when you click on a link inside any site, the browser screen goes white, waits a couple of seconds, then it starts rendering the page, loading images, etc.

But some websites, after you click links, the current page stays put even though you see the browser's preloaders spinning and the server processes the request in the background. But it never goes white. It will only display their empty background of the next page, and only for a split-second.

How do websites achieve this?

Here's two example links for comparison:

1. http://www.blackhatworld.com/ (no white background)
2. http://www.moneymakerdiscussion.com/ (shows white background)

Answer (score 1):

Grigore, I believe this is related to the content of the pages, especially SWFobjects and JavaScript. To remove the white screen try to move the JavaScript at the bottom of your  in HTML (so it loads later) and reduce/remove SWFobjects (Flash Ads, Games, etc.).
Hope this helps!